# Querying intermediate results in SageMaker GroundTruth

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

Can I somehow query the results of a labeling job in SageMaker Ground Truth while the job isn't completed?

When I select a labeling job, the "Query output" button is greyed out until the job is completed:
[image]

It feels ridiculous to have to wait for the entire job to finish to see the results. Querying/looking at intermediate results is possible in all the other labeling tools I've used.